# Happy New Prime Year!

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

It happens that next year 2011 is prime, while outgoing 2010 is
highly composite in the sense that the number of its distinct prime factors
is 4, maximal possible for a year $< 2310$.

Let me denote by $s(n)$ the number of distinct prime factors of $n$
and note that $s(2011)=1$, $s(2012)=2$ and $s(2013)=3$. I wonder
whether there is a rigorous argument or some heuristic considerations
to show that, for each $k\ge1$, there exist (infinitely many integers)
$n$ satisfying $s(n+1)=1$, $s(n+2)=2$, $\dots$, $s(n+k)=k$.

This can be thought as a generalization of the infiniteness of primes
($k=1$), but I ask this question for curiosity only.

Happy New Prime Year 2011! (Please do not count the exclamation mark as factorial.)

Comment: Is it already the new year in Australia ?  

Comment: Not yet but it will come much earlier than to other places. :-)

Comment: Though in a cultural sense, the New Year starts (started) in Israel and India a bit earlier, as their years are phase shifted ahead of the US/EU calendars, and in China the New Year starts a bit later as their year's end is phase shifted after the calendar used to demarcate the passage of time on MO. And numerically they're using different starting points for their "zero" year along with being phase shifted as a difference. Do the Australians hang their calendars upside down? ;>)

Comment: In deference to @Frictionless-Jellyfish 's answer, I was thinking of deleting my comment-like answer, except for the fact that $M$ divisble by $k!$ does not make as much sense as having $M$ divisible by the product of the first $k$ prime numbers, or of $k$ distinct prime numbers.  $2010$ factors into 2x3x5x67, and is not divisible by $4!=24$. The first example with 4 factors has to be divisible by 210, 5 factors has to be divisible by 2310.

Comment: If there is an example for each integer k, then it is also an example for each (k-1), so there are either infinitely many for each k, or there is a k for which there is none.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.12.28

Comment: But then, that may be why you say "(infinitely many integers)" instead of "infinitely many integers".  Gerhard "Reading A Second Time Helps" Paseman, 2010.12.28

Comment: Mea culpa. The first example with four factors does NOT have to be divisible by 210, nor 5 by 2310, as I show in an example below where starting with n=1866 and k=4 gets you the prime year 1867, the two-prime factor year 1868, the three-prime-factor year 1869, and the four-prime factor 1870.  See answer below for factors.  

Comment: 2011 divides $53^{10}-1$.  Anyone know why (or how) Wolfram Alpha selects this fact to report?

Comment: No, but it must be a standard thing it looks for.  It reports 2010 divides 29^6-1.

Comment: 2011 is not just prime; it is also the sum of a prime number of consecutive primes:

2011=157+163+167+173+179+181+191+193+197+199+211

Answer (score 8):

You missed the excitement of 1998, with $1999=1999, 2000=2^4 \cdot 5^3, 2001=3 \cdot 23 \cdot 29,$ and $2002=2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$

A quick set of thoughts, too long to fit in a comment:

this requires finding a "prime gap" of length $k-1$, since $s(n+1)=1$ means <strike>that $n+1$ is prime</strike> that $n+1$ is either prime or a power of a prime, but the next $k-1$ digits are composite since s(n+x)>1 for $2 \le x \le k$.   This also means that $s(n+2)=2$ only because $s(n+2)$ is even, thus $2$ is one of the factors and implies that $(n+2)/2$ is prime (or that $(n+2)/2^j$ is prime for some $j \in \mathbb{Z}$), since $n+2$ only has two factors and one of them is $2$ (or $2^j$).

For $s(n+k)$ to have $k$ distinct prime factors means that it has to be at minimum a product of the first $k$ prime numbers, while it definitely has to be a multiple of the product of $k$ prime numbers.  So the two key restrictions are that s(n+k) is $k$-composite (has $k$ prime factors) and that both (n+1) and (n+2)/2 are prime numbers.

Hmm, I thought something about the fact that either s(n+2) or s(n+4) would be divisible by $4$ while the other would be divisible by $2$ but not by $4$ would play some role in this.

Here are some quick results from running "bash", "factor", and "sed" and "awk" at the command line:

If you want an ascending run of 1,2, and 3 prime factors, the smallest example starts at $n=63$, with $64=2^6, 65=5 \cdot 13, 66=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11$

If you want an ascending run of 1,2,3, and 4 prime factors, we already missed the exciting years of $n=1866$ and $n=1998$

```
1867: 1867
1868: 2 2 467
1869: 3 7 89
1870: 2 5 11 17

1999: 1999
2000: 2 2 2 2 5 5 5
2001: 3 23 29
2002: 2 7 11 13
```

And the next few years with ascending runs of 1,2,3, and 4 prime factors will start after the years 3216, 4056, and 4176 with 3217, 4057, and 4177 as prime years.  Unfortunately, these computational results are not giving me the germ of any shortcut or understanding.  There are also some descending sequences in terms of the number of prime factors, and their placement also does not help.

If you want an ascending run of 1,2,3,4, and 5 prime factors, we have to wait almost half-a-million years to get to the exciting years of $n=491850$ and $n=521880$ for $k=5$

```
491851: 491851
491852: 2 2 122963
491853: 3 19 8629
491854: 2 11 79 283
491855: 5 7 13 23 47

521881: 521881
521882: 2 260941
521883: 3 3 3 3 17 379
521884: 2 2 11 29 409
521885: 5 7 13 31 37
```

Now with four numbers computed and found, I searched the OEIS and found the corresponding sequence.  Since the Online Encyclopedia already has this sequence, I'm hanging up my computational hat and heading off to work.  :)

> http://oeis.org/A086560
>
> Start of first run of n successive numbers in which i-th number has exactly i distinct prime divisors for i = 1..n
>
> ```
> 2, 5, 64, 1867, 491851, 17681491, 35565206671
> ```
>
> J.-M. De Koninck, Ces nombres qui nous fascinent, Entry 64, p. 23, Ellipses, Paris 2008.

Comment: $n+3$ has to be divisible by $3$ and must have two other prime factors not including $2$.

Comment: I meant to say that either "(n+2) or (n+4)" would be divisible by 4 while the other would be divisible by 2 but not by 4; not "s(n+2) or s(n+4)"

Comment: and as you say in your question, such a sequence requires that the base number be larger than the product of the first $k$ primes.

Comment: n+3 does not have to be a multiple of 3.  383 is prime, and 385=5x7x11.   Gerhard "Ask Me About Smooth Numbers" Paseman, 2010.12.28

Comment: @Gerhard-Paseman, oops, I messed that up.  n+1 has to be prime, n+2 has to be divisible by 2, n+3 does not have to be divisible by 3.  But either n+2 or n+4 has to be divisble by 3.

Comment: If by n+2 or n+4 you mean n+2 or n+3, then I agree.  Gerhard Paseman, 2010.12.28


Comment: wow, i'm tired.  Yes, my correction has an error in it!  Yes, n+2 has to be divisble by 2, but I really meant to say n+3 is divible by 3 and if it isn't then n+5 is divisble by 3.  (I'll try to explain that again more coherently later.  But please see computational results for interesting "prime years" for up to 4 factors.

Comment: I would tell you to go to sleep, but that might come across as an insult.  In the meantime, I'll see about replicating your results with awk.  Gerhard "You Only Need One Tool" Paseman, 2010.12.28

Comment: There are 185 $n$ values in the range 1-100000 (with values for n ranging from 1866 to 99906) for $k=4$.

Comment: @Gerhard-Paseman: Perlify it into a one-liner, and I'll see your code and raise it to APL! Or maybe get out the punch-cards and do some FORTRAN-WATFOR.

Comment: Thanks, S-in-B. Yes, I would prefer to be back to 1867 or 1999 just because they give lengthier intervals... On the other hand, I hope I don't make you sleepless.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why does $n+1$ have to be prime?

Comment: @A-Rex asaurus, the $n+1$ being prime was my original conjecture which I did not edit out when I found the first counter example for $k=3$, $n=63$, with $n+1=64=2^6$, $n+2=65=5\cdot13$, $n+3=66=2\cdot3\cdot11$.  So $n+1$ only has to be prime (or a power of a prime) if $n$ is even; if $n$ is odd, $n+1$ can be a power of an even prime thus it must be a power of $2$.

Comment: An interesting "argument" goes as follows: 
for large k, of the k(k+1)/2 factors in the run of k numbers, about k/2 are 2, about k/3 are 3, and so on for the first few primes.  Counting all the factors suggests summing {1/p_i} up to (k+1)/2, which needs the first n primes where log(log(n)) would roughly be about k/2, thus examples of such runs should be roughly exp(exp(k/2)).  The biggest problem with this argument is that it seems to work for small k.  Perhaps someone knows a good argument with a similar conclusion?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.12.29

Comment: Thanks, S-in-B, for the newer edition and especially for the link to De Koninck (is it available online?).

Comment: Here is a different "argument" with hopefully an easier path toward justification.  Since n often has log(log(n)) distinct factors, it would be highly unlikely that all of the k numbers in the sequence would deviate from that.  Thus one of the k numbers n must have size at least somewhere around exp(exp(k/2)), give or take a few orders of orders of magnitude.  How about that?  Gerhard "What's a Googleplex Between Colleagues?" Paseman, 2011.01.02

Answer (score 7):

As it was pointed out to me by Han Wu, 2010 wasn't that boring from the prime numbers point of view:

2010 = 2*3*5*(7+11+13+17+19)

Comment: Ricardo, I would expect that there is no "primary" boring year at all! :-)

Comment: @Ricardo and @Wadim-Zudilin, yes the numerologists will see a way to make every year interesting, and the paradox of the first un-interesting year becoming interesting because of the fact that it **is** the first un-interesting year. ;>)  Also, see Mayan, Hebrew, Chinese, Indian, and many other cultural artefacts for different origins and phase-shifts for yearly and weekly and monthly calendar objects.  It's amazing how human beings have dissected the night sky and the numbers we pluck out of the sky and thin air.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the question you are asking is still open. It has only (relatively) recently been shown that $s(n)=s(n+1)=A$ has infinitely many solutions for $A\ge 3$. This was shown by Schlage-Puchta in 2003. This article by Goldston, Graham, Pintz, and Yildirim discusses this and related questions:

http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2636

Remark: your arithmetic function $s(\cdot)$ is usually denoted $\omega(\cdot)$ nowadays, but was denoted $\nu(\cdot)$ by Ramanujan.

Comment: Thanks, John, for the link to related problems. With F-Jellyfish's comment above my question is definitely answered. Yes, I know about the $\omega$ (but not $\nu$) notation, although I was not convinced it is standard enough and I did not wish for respondents use 6 symbols for $\omega$ instead of just one for $s$.

Comment: Thanks, Micah, for turning from John into Micah. Your newer name is nicer!

Comment: I read the meta thread about posting with real names (and was convinced to do so).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another pattern I learned from [Bharath Kumar Annamaneni](http://www.google.com/profiles/bharath4everyone#buzz) in his buzz post.

2011= 157 + 163 + 167 + 173 + 179 + 181 + 191 + 193 + 197 + 199 + 211 .

2011, Being A Prime Number Itself, Is Also A Sum Of 11 Consecutive Prime Numbers .
Wow.

Comment: Check Steven Landsburg's comment to the question.  GRP 2011.01.03

Comment: I guess there is a source for this particular example. I also got this example outside MO from a friend...

Comment: I am sorry I did not see that. A possible first source is prime pages: http://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/2011.html

Comment: Elohemahab, thanks for the link, it's cute: "[2011 is] the year terminating the smallest quadruplet of successive prime years that leaps over a millennium with increasing gaps $2^n$ ($n=1,2,3$): 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011." Let me add that 2027 ($=2011+2^4$ and prime) ends this quintuplet...

Comment: Another piece about 2011: "The smallest four digit prime assigned as an Australian postcode. It belongs to Kings Cross and Woollomolloo, New South Wales." I am quite close to the place (although there are closer people on MO). I love Aussie names: Wool-lo-mol-loo... oooo

Comment: Happy traveling!

Comment: Thanks, Elohemahab! To be honest, I am not traveling but living in this paradise. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I decided to share this awk code to compute s(n), primarily because I like that it uses only addition and the distributive law, and not factoring, to compute s(n).  It also uses a bit of string processing and hash-table look up, but is a nice example of the use of associative arrays.  I also like it because it uses $O(\pi(n)\log(n))$ bytes of memory,
essentially one entry per prime number less than n. Apologies to sleepless in beantown:  I prefer obfuscated awk and nice algorithms to one-liners in Perl, so do not accept his challenge made in a comment on his answer.

```
BEGIN{  LIM = 10000 ; SEP = "," 
prev = count[1] = count[2] = count[3] = SENTINEL = 0
dir[1] = 1 ;        dir[2] = 0 ;        dir[3] = -1
str[1] = " / at " ; str[2] = " = at " ; str[3] = " \\ at "
notify[1] = notify[3] = 3; notify[2] = 6
```

for( n = 2 ; n < LIM ; n++ ) { # cmp means composite
  if (n in cmp) {  split(cmp[n], fl, SEP) ;  delete cmp[n] }
  else { # n is prime; make up factor list from scratch
     fl[1] = n ; fl[2] = SENTINEL }
  for(f = fl[j=1] ; f != SENTINEL ; f = fl[++j] ) {
     if ((nn = (n+f)) in cmp) cmp[nn] = f SEP cmp[nn]
     else cmp[nn] = f SEP SENTINEL }
  s = j - 1

for (k in dir) { count[k] = (prev == (s - dir[k]))?(count[k] + 1): 1
    if (count[k] > notify[k]) print count[k] str[k] n ":" s }
  prev = s
} }

Sample output verifies the results of sleepless in beantown, plus shows that there are long runs where s is constant: 2=s(2302)=...=s(2308) .  It suggests that there is a function f(s) such that there are at most f(s) consecutive numbers with value s.  I
suspect f(1)=4, but do not yet have a proof.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.12.29

Comment: Thanks, Gerhard! It's almost the end of 2010.12.30 here...

Comment: Since multiples of 2 are involved, showing that f(1)=4 boils down to case checking.  Since there is only one pair of adjacent concsecutive powers of 2, the case checking is not that tedious.  So I now think I have a proof that f(1)=4.  I would have thought f(2) to be 6 or less, but simulation shows that to be in error.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" paseman, 2010.12.30